# How to write active record using using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How to write active record for **price less than or equal to** and **price less than or equal to by scope** in Ruby?

I tried like this:

```
scope :price, -> (price_lteq_or_price_gteq) { where("price_paisas >= ? or price_paisas <= ?", price_lteq_or_price_gteq, price_lteq_or_price_gteq)}
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @properties = Property.where(:status=>'1')
  @properties = @properties.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @properties = @properties.price(params[:price_lteq]) if params[:price_lteq].present?
  @properties = @properties.price(params[:price_gteq]) if params[:price_gteq].present?
end
```

When I tried like this, I got query like this:

```
SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE
`properties`.`status` = '1' AND (price_paisas >= '000' or price_paisas <= '000')
AND (price_paisas >= '49900' or price_paisas <= '49900')
```

What I need is active record like this

```
SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE
`properties`.`status` = '1' AND
(price_paisas >= '000' and price_paisas <='49900')
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Scope:**

*price_gteq = 0, price_lteq= 49900*

```
scope :price, -> (price_lteq, price_gteq) { where("price_paisas >= ? or price_paisas <= ?", price_gteq, price_lteq)}
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
 @properties = Property.where(:status=>'1')
 @properties = @properties.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
 @properties = @properties.price(params[:price_lteq],params[:price_gteq]) if params[:price_lteq] && params[:price_gteq] 
end
```